# JavaScript Array reflection

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, prototype

how to loop through JavaScript Array member functions, the following code doesn't work :(

```
for (var i in Array.prototype){
    alert(i)
} //show nothing 

for (var i in []){
   alert(i)
} // show nothing
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the native prototypal properties are enumerable, but you can find out exactly what you're looking for in the ECMA spec:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

You can only enumerate through properties which you defined, eg:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function(){};

x = {};

for ( var prop in x ) {
    alert( prop );
}
```

would alert:

> foo

Another useful tip is that you can use `object.hasOwnProperty( property )` inside a `for..in loop` to branch only if the object directly owns a property, and the property does not descend from the constructor's prototype, of which all objects pretty much descend from `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't loop through native methods.